# What’s the name of a USB stick when its label is empty?

Tags: debian, usb-drive

I changed the label of my USB stick to empty by using the e2label command, then it is mounted as /media/USER/NAME in Debian, I want to know what the NAME stands for and how to change it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with _debian_, it's something that's done by the automounter called by your DE so tag the question appropriately. Assuming your DE is _GNOME 3_ which underneath uses `udisks2` to automount - if you check the source code you can see how the path is constructed e.g. for the `NAME` part start reading at [line 951](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/blob/master/src/udiskslinuxfilesystem.c#L951)

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what NAME reads? 

Is this a placeholder for something a command is outputting? Where are you reading this device path from? 
Can you use the `lsblk` command to locate the block device and paste the output? This would be helpful in me finding out what you need/want to change.
The USB should be listed as `/dev/sd[x]` with x being an alphanumeric character

change block device label with e2label: `$ e2label device [ new-label ]`

device can be the entire drive or a partition.

`/dev/sda` is the entire drive

`/dev/sda1` is the first partition of device `/dev/sda`

`/dev/sda2` is the second partition of device `/dev/sda`

eg. to show the label of `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda3`

`$ e2label /dev/sda1` 

`/boot`

`$ e2label /dev/sda3`

`/`

To change the label for `/dev/sda3`, do as follows,
`$ e2label /dev/sda3 changed-label`

and to confirm the change was done sucessfully,

`$ e2label /dev/sda3`

`changed-label`

if you want a `/` in front of the label,

`$ e2label /dev/sda3 /changed-label`

to verify that the change was done,

`$ e2label /dev/sda3`

`/changed-label`

if you want the server to be able to boot next time round, ensure changes are made to /etc/fstab as well. Otherwise, on the next boot, you may be prompted with errors, eg.

`fsck.ext3: Unable to resolve 'LABEL=/boot'`
`fsck.ext3: Unable to resolve 'LABEL=/'`

Source with more info: http://www.xssist.com/blog/e2label,%20fdisk,%20etc%20fstab,%20mount,%20linux%20rescue,%20rescue%20disk,%20CentOS.htm

Comment: I just changed the label of the first partition, I now know it is the label of the entire stick, how to change it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not know if I understand. You changed the name of the partition? Not the device? To change the devices, do it without the number at the end `sdx` no number

Comment: Of course e2label cannot change the label of the stick